# How to enable Hardcore mode

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

Why `Hardcore` mode is disabled and grayed out in gameplay menu settings? I am an "expert" of Fallout 3 and I would like to start my first playthrough in New Vegas with `Hardcore` mode `ON`. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that Hardcore mode is only available after you first start the game and finish a few quests in the starting town. I too looked for this option and had it greyed out, but when i tried to leave the starting area it asked me if i wanted to play HC or not, explaining what the difference is.

Comment: The offer to switch to Hardcore mode is made as you leave Dr. Mitchell house: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ain%27t_That_a_Kick_in_the_Head_(quest)#Notes

Comment: This answer is correct, you MUST leave the DR house first before you can enable it, and then it'll even give you the option to enable it.